# How to slide through 1 UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to create an multiple UITableView or UICollectionView that can slide through like shown in the screenshot. So the Edit profile and Photos are 2 different UITableView or UICollectionView.
Any good way to create it? I just too new in Swift.
Thanks guys.[image]

Comment: maybe you can use this library
(https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu)

Comment: https://github.com/aslanyanhaik/youtube-iOS this is not the appropriate link but it can help you to achieve what you want

Comment: what about using a [UISegmentControl](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/).

And show the required view, hide the others.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz can we slide through UIsegmentcontrol?

Comment: No. It will allow to select one of the two options, not slide. For sliding, either use the libraires or use a [pageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller?changes=_4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're lots of useful libs like:

1) [PageMenu](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu)

2) [SwiftPageMenu](https://github.com/tamanyan/SwiftPageMenu)

3) [PagingMenuController](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController)

4) [Parchment](https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment)